# Wrong wsimport command line call

Tags: java, netbeans-8, wsimport

since last week I have a problem compiling my web services with Netbeans IDE 8.0. 
If I run a clean-build, I saw this wsimport call in the Netbeans output window:

```
command line: wsimport"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin\java.exe" -d C:\projects\MetricEvaluator\build\generated\jax-wsCache\service\MetricEvaluator -extension -Xendorsed -keep -s C:\projects\MetricEvaluator\build\generated\jax-wsCache\service\MetricEvaluator -encoding UTF-8 -verbose -Xnocompile -catalog C:\projects\MetricEvaluator\catalog.xml C:\projects\MetricEvaluator/src/conf/xml-resources/web-services/MetricEvaluator/wsdl/MetricEvaluator.wsdl
```

I don't know why now the "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin\java.exe" part comes directly after the wsimport. If I copy this call into a console and delete this part, the web service sources are generated without problems.

Does someone know where this comes from and how I can fix this? Thanks for your help in advance.

Regards,
Boo

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by stopping Netbeans IDE and deleting the Netbeans folders from C:\Users\myUserName\AppData\Roaming. After this I restarted Netbeans and open again my web service projects. Now the service classes are generated like expected and the wsimport call looks correct.

Unfortunately, I have no idea why that happened.

Regards,
Boo